# Switching to a different UIViewController (no push)

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to switch from one `UIViewController` to another. I can do this by pushing the new `UIViewController` onto the navigation stack but this doesn't achieve the functionality I desire.

I want to replace the active `UIViewController` with another. The active `UIViewController` is not the root controller.

I've seen this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234763/switching-to-different-uitableviewcontrollers-with-uisegementedcontrol) but it looks a little hacky, has anyone got any other solutions?

Comment: You can always push your new UIViewController on top of the navigation stack and then remove the second from top ViewController (your old UIViewController).

Comment: Thanks @Singhal2, this has lead me to a solution which I am happy with. I add the second view controller as a child, remove the first and then use the SetViewContollers method of the NavigationContoller.